# How to read a twitter user's profile in a bash script

Tags: bash, twitter, raspbian

Changing my twitter profile is free, quick, simple, and I can do it from anywhere in the world with my phone.

As such I would like to use my Twitter profile as a way to pat a watchdog bash script (on raspbarian) - when the profile changes, the watchdog detects it and would then perform an action.

I was using the gdrive app to check the last modified date on a shared Google Drive doc, but some days I would hit a daily quota unit limit and the watchdog would not get its pat.

Without providing the full script, what I have now is something like the following logic:

```
#!/bin/bash
timeStampOld="$(gdrive info ID#)"
while
do
  timeStampNew="$(gdrive info ID#)"
  if [[ $timeStampOld = $timeStampNew ]];then
    echo "No change. Pat watchdog."
  else
    echo "Watchdog not happy. Run (the corrective action script) for your lives!"
    timeStampOld=$timeStampNew
  fi
done
```

How do I do the same thing, but by reading my twitter profile instead of the gdrive command? Is there a single command line that can retrieve my twitter profile?

If there is a better, free, simple, option to read a change I can make online with my phone, I'm also open to other suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use twitter api and do this in `Python`?

Comment: I have a working script in bash, except for this one element. I have no experience with APIs other than knowing roughly what they do, but that'll be part of the learning experience. I'll try python for my next little project, I promise.